# Aggregate and list withCount by grouped column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I want to make 24-hour trend posts. My intention is to collect all the likes in the posts.slug column that I have grouped and list them accordingly.

```
$trends = Post::withCount('likes')
    ->orderByDesc('likes_count')
    ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay())
    ->groupBy('posts.slug')
    ->get();
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: @UğurArıcı Question; my code is wrong how do i fix it. It just sorts by the number of likes on a post. I want it to collect all likes in posts.slug column...

Comment: It collects all of them. You want a sum of them?

Comment: @UğurArıcı Yes, i want to sum and order by this total.

Comment: Do you have more than 1 post with exact same `slug` ?

Comment: Yes there are many posts with the same slug.